# Shopify Liquid show custom div after 5th product in collection

Tags: collections, shopify, liquid

I would like to show a custom div after the 5th product in my collection in shopify. Does anyone know how I can do this in liquid?

Answer (score 0):

End the end of the for loop for the products, put a conditional like

```
{% if forloop.index == 5 %}
   <div></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[liquid for loop iteration](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/)

use `limit`/ `offset`

```
{% for item in array limit: 4 %}
  item less than or equal to 4
{% endfor %}
{% for item in array offset: 4 %}
  item greater than 4 (5)
{% endfor %}
```

or  use `forloop.index`

```
{% for item in array %}
  {% if forloop.index < 5 %}
    do something for less than 5
  {% else %}
    do something greater than or equal to 5
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```